# jQuery on load not working with iframe

Tags: javascript, jquery, iframe

Here's the code I'm using to target the iframe element generated from a top bar plugin in WordPress (I need to style it dynamically based on some other conditions which is why I'm using jQuery). It does not have an ID, so I'm targeting it using a class. But it doesn't work. I can never get an "iframe loaded" in the console.

```
jQuery('iframe.topbar-iframe.topbar').on('load', function () {
        console.log("iframe loaded");
    });
```

The iframe does load later than the other parts of the page. I did try using the above inside `jQuery(window).on('load'....` but that didn't work either.

How should I trigger a jQuery function after an iframe has loaded?

Comment: Take a look at [this](http://jsfiddle.net/umYkV/2014/) or [this](http://jsfiddle.net/umYkV/2013/)

Comment: try `on('ready')` in place of `on('load')`